# Getter Failing in PHP

Tags: php, getter

I'm feeling a little stupid right now, but it seems as though there's a bug in my getter method - pretty much the simplest code you can write.

This code works correctly:

```
class HvZPlayer extends User{
     public $hvz_status;

     public function __construct($data, $db){
         parent::__construct($data);
         $this->hvz_status  = $data['hvz_status'];
     }
}

$test = new HvZPlayer(array('hvz_status'=>"testing"), "TestDB");
echo $test->hvz_status;
```

But this code does not:

```
 class HvZPlayer extends User{
      private $hvz_status;

      public function __construct($data, $db){
           parent::__construct($data);
           $this->hvz_status    = $data['hvz_status'];
      }

      public function get_hvz_status(){
           return $this->hvz_status;
      }
}

$test = new HvZPlayer(array('hvz_status'=>"testing"), "TestDB");
echo $test->get_hvz_status;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Wow...it's late.  Took me two hours to figure out I'd left the empty parentheses off my method calls...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parentheses on the function call.

```
echo $test->get_hvz_status();
```